# Adding X-Y plots to an existing chart in VBA

Tags: excel, plot, vba

I’d like to write visual basic code that adds a “new series” to an existing plot.  I’ve already managed to write the code that will select that data I want to add.  So to complete the operation I did it in excel, recording the following macro:

```
‘desired data already selected a column of x values and one of y values to be plotted
Selection.Copy
Sheets("XVSER").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
ActiveChart.Paste
```

However, what this recorded macro does not show is I wanted to add the data as a “new series”, even though this option was explicitly selected while recording the macro.  So when I run the macro it does not do the same thing I did will recording it, and adds the data to an existing series instead of creating a new series for it.

Surely there must be a way of specifying in VBA that I’d like a new series.  I just don’t know how, or where to find documentation, and what I found already on stackoverflow, was difficult for me to understand, and seemed to require a different approach, which I’d rather avoid, since I’ve already developed the code to successfully select the data I want, and to select the chart I want to paste it in.

Answer (score 0):

When recording MACROS with charts, not allways the result comes out the same as when recorded it. You will need to familiarize yourself with some of the `ChartObject` properties.

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddSelectionasNewSeries()

Dim ChtRng As Range
Dim ChtObj As ChartObject
Dim Ser As Series

' set the selection as range >> However, try avoid using slection
Set ChtRng = Selection

' set the chart object
Set ChtObj = Sheets("XVSER").ChartObjects("Chart 3")

' add a new series with the Selection
ChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection.Add ChtRng   

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick and detailed answer.  I’ve tried it:  it now adds the plot I want, but for some reason it adds a 2nd plot I don’t want.  (The “selection” consists of two non-adjacent columns of numbers, one with the x values and the other with the corresponding y values.)

You write “You will need to familiarize yourself with some of the ChartObject properties.”  But how do I go about doing that?

Finally in regard to
    Option Explicit
I’m not sure what that does, but presumably it is needed, but is there a way to deactivate it again after use?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use SeriesCollection.Paste, which has parameters to specify whether to add points or series and so forth. The Macro Recorder doesn't know this.

Replace

```
ActiveChart.Paste
```

with

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Paste Rowcol:=xlColumns, Serieslabels:=False, _
    CategoryLabels:=True, NewSeries:=True
```